# How to expand both sides to fit browser window?

Tags: css, html

```
<div class="main"> width:100%; background:grey;

<div class="page2"> width:940px; background: grey;

<div class="content"> width:940px; background: white;
```

is there any option in css to expand the both sides?
The "content" should be in center as width:940px and then I need to expand both sides to fit browser window.

Example:

if it is a 1440 screen then "content" = 940px and left & right side should be expand to 250px.

if it is a 1640 screen then "content" = 940px and left & right side should be expand to 350px.

Comment: what is the problem

Comment: https://homedone.co.uk/mattresses/silentnight-special-sleep-3-single-mattress.html plz look at the page.

Comment: I need the tab sides to be fit to the browser window (Product Description, Additional Information, Reviews, Shipping Information)

Comment: you need a full width of that tab slider right

Comment: yes you are right...

Comment: you mean 100% not 940px

Comment: actually I need to keep the 940px + expand both sides

Comment: I am not understand

Comment: if it's 3 column table I need the center column should be  940px then the side columns should margin-left:0, margin-right:0 something like this

Comment: I need the tab like this http://screencast.com/t/qvWS5RURHAFT

Comment: Sorry it possible but you need to change lot's of things so please try your end

Answer (score 0):

I think you  need look like this
[image]

After Closing the header-container you need to start your nav-conatiner and add this CSS if i am wright it will fulfill you need.

## nav {

```
position: relative;
width: 940px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

}